# Nodejs getting no data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my first node.js app, so bear with me :-)
I had tutorials and examples working, but when I try to do it myself I get no data at all. And Im out of ideas to why.

This is my model:

```
const expenseSchema = mongodb.Schema({
   _id: {
     type: String
   },
   name: {
     type: String
   }
});
const expensecategory = module.exports = mongodb.model('expensecategory', expenseSchema);

module.exports.getExpense = function(parms, callback){
  console.log('LETS GO!!!..: ' + parms);
//  expensecategory.find({}, callback);
//  expensecategory.findOne({ "_id": "OFFICE" }, callback);
//  expensecategory.find({ "_id": "OFFICE" }, callback);
  const query = {
     _id: "OFFICE"
  }
  expensecategory.findOne(query, callback);

// I cannot get any data, no matter what I do

}
```

This is my Route

```
router.get('/property/:propertyID', function(req, res) {

  console.log("property propertyID: " + req.params.propertyID);
  const propertyID =  req.params.propertyID;

  console.log('Calling getTranslate: ' + propertyID);
  Expense.getExpense(propertyID, (err, result) => {

      if(err) throw err;

      console.log('ERR? ' + err);
      console.log('RESULT? ' + result);

      if(!result){
        return res.json({msg: 'Nothing Found!! ' + result});
      } else {
         res.json({success:'' + result})
        console.log('SUCCESS!!: ' + result);
        console.log('_id: ' + result._id);
        console.log('name: ' + result.name);
      }

  });
});
```

And this is the result from my terminal window[image]

The funny thing is that these two find something

expensecategory.find({}, callback);

expensecategory.findOne({ "_id": "OFFICE" }, callback);

But the data they find is null

I checked mongodb already and the table is ok with data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Johnny - I will check that one out right away

Comment: If you enable Mongoose debug output via `mongoose.set('debug', true);`, I expect you'll see that it's using the expensecategories collection.

Comment: @JohnnyHK you were right!!   const ExpenseModel = module.exports = mongodb.model('expensecategory', expenseSchema); - that one did NOT work.... but this one did....... const ExpenseModel = module.exports = mongodb.model('ExpenseModel', expenseSchema, 'expensecategory');

Comment: Great. Yep, very common trap in Mongoose.

Comment: Why the "f" dont they write about this in the tutorials.  Been trying to fix it for 5 hours! - And thanks for the debug tip!!